# Check full value of a long string in the VB6 IDE

Tags: vb6, ide

I have a string 'sSQL' that contains a very long tsql statement. I need to check what its value is while debugging. I usually just use ?sSQL in the immediate window but this is truncating the first half and only giving me the end half.

So is there an alternative way to see the full value using the vb6 sp5 dev environment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's *that long*, save it to a text file. Have a debug method:

```
sub SaveStringToDebugFile(s as string)
  ...
end sub
```

and then call it from the immediate window:

```
SaveStringToDebugFile sSQL
```

Comment: I have ended up just doing this thanks. Annoying vb6 limitation.

Answer (score 15):

For debugging, `Clipboard.Clear: Clipboard.SetText ssql` then paste into notepad.

Answer (score 9):

While execution is paused on the breakpoint you could type in the immediate window:

```
Debug.Print(sSql)
```

;-)

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I can't believe this has upvotes. The OP said their issue was with output being truncated when using ?sSQL. ?sSQL is an alias for Debug.Print(sSQL), so this would provide exactly the same results.

Comment: After seven years, busted)

Answer (score 7):

One way is to use write the string out to a file. You can do this in a single line in the immediate window by using Line continuations, e.g.:

```
Open "C:\SQL.TXT" For Append As #1: Write #1,sSQL : Close #1
```

Note: You'll need to change C:\SQL.Txt to a path that you can write to depending on your OS.

Answer (score 2):

Erm, the immediate window doesn't truncate (except at 200 lines of 1023 characters). Have you just tried pressing the home key or scrolling left?

Comment: and if you have a 200KB SQL statement, you have FAR bigger problems... :p

Comment: It is over 200 lines and therefore does truncate... I'm dealing with moving stored procedures. 200k would assume that each line is full of characters which of course is unlikely.

Comment: Don't put new lines in the string :) (or `?replace(ssql,vbcrlf," ")`)

Answer (score 1):

Check the length of the "long" string using the Immediate:

```
?len(sSQL)
 4221
```

then knowing the size you can start getting chunks of string using Mid function:

```
?Mid(sSQL, 1, 500)

?Mid(sSQL, 500, 1000)

?Mid(sSQL, 1000, 1500)
```

Comment: good idea but this one is 14288 characters, could be a bit cumbersome.